# Smallest sets of spheres that envelop a cube

Tags: geometry

It is trivial to find the smallest sphere that envelopes a cube. Next, 8 overlapping spheres can envelop the cube with a shorter cross distance.

What is the next smallest number of (differently sized, overlapping) spheres that will envelop the cube with a shorter cross distance?

Comment: 3 spheres is the minimum sufficient.

Comment: @Arjang: Two spheres, I would say.

Comment: @TonyK : Two spheres doesn't envelope a volume but 3 spheres can

Comment: @Arjang: see my answer.

Comment: What is a *cross distance*?

Comment: @GerryMyerson the distance across the set of spheres. Along the normal vector of one of the cube faces

Comment: I'm not sure what "distance across the set of spheres" means, as the spheres may not match up in any useful way. Also, distance may be different depending on which cube face you use. Do you try all three pairs of faces, and keep the smallest one?

Comment: Please, Koichi, clarify.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm looking for the tighest fit, so if the solution is not symmetrical, then the goal should be to minimize the largest distance.

Comment: Put a different way, one can try to find the dimensions of the smallest cube that envelops the set of spheres that envelop the original cube

Comment: And let's be clear: 1 sphere is sufficient to envelop ANY polyhedron. The tighest fit is found with an infinite number of infitesimally small spheres covering the faces. I am looking for the lowest numbers of spheres that reduce the size of the "foam" around the sphere. First 1 sphere, then 8? Then 26?

Comment: OK. Have you tried solving the analogous question one dimension down? covering a square with overlapping circles? Maybe it's easier to visualize that question, and it might show you the way to go at the 3-dim problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, sort of. The key seems to be to cover the edges, then the rest falls in place. Same reasoning in 2 or 3 dimensions. Also it seems best to use the same size spheres. But I can't be sure that this holds true for all solutions.

Comment: So, what numbers do you get in two dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

To envelop a $2\times 2\times 2$ cube with a single sphere, we need a radius of $\sqrt 3$. But to envelop a $2\times 2\times 1$ cuboid with a single sphere, we only need a radius of $\sqrt{1^2+1^2+(\frac12)^2}=\sqrt\frac94$. And clearly two such spheres are enough to envelop a $2\times 2\times 2$ cube.

**Edited to add:** This may or may not answer the OP's question, depending on what "cross distance" means. We are currently waiting on a workable definition.

Comment: @Thank you Tony, I see your point now.